# CoreDispatcher.HasThreadAccess "breaking change"

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, mvvmcross

I am taking over an application developed with MvvmCross.vNext.
While trying to update it with MvvmCross.V3, I found the following breaking change: in the constructor of the MainViewModel, we show the LoginViewModel (ShowViewModel()). 
It worked fine in vNext.
But with V3, the LoginView doesn't show.
After a **long** search, I found out that the following code, added in **MvxStoreMainThreadDispatcher.RequestMainThreadAction** :

```
        if (_uiDispatcher.HasThreadAccess)
        {
            action();
            return true;
        }
```

was responsible for my troubles.
If I comment it out, my application works as previously, but I guess this code is there for some reasons...
Do you have any suggestions ?
Can I force the previous behavior without changing MvvmCross source code?
Should I refactor the code to handle the LoginView differently ?
Thanks in advance for your comments.
Philippe

Comment: Can you provide some context/code about how/when you are navigating to that login?

Comment: Scratch that last comment  - will answer soon

Comment: Hi Stuart, Actually if you call ShowViewModel<AnyModel> in the ctor, you'll see the difference between vNExt and Vee Threee  Philippe

Answer (score 1):

> While trying to update it with MvvmCross.V3, I found the following breaking change: in the constructor of the MainViewModel, we show the LoginViewModel (ShowViewModel()). It worked fine in vNext.

I think your constructor navigation would have broken on several platforms in any MvvmCross version. To be honest, I think you were lucky it worked before.

The problem is that ViewModels are constructed (or located) during View events such as `ViewDidLoad`, `OnNavigatedTo`, and `OnCreate` - and these events are normally 
called during 'page transitions'

To work around this you will **need** to move your login navigation out of the constructor.

How you do this depends on your app

- if you do need the Home->Login backstack, then you can trigger off some async or time delay or you can trigger off some other View event such as something like `ViewDidAppear`
- if you don't need that backstack then the way I normally implement this sort of thing is to use a custom `IMvxAppStart` - something like:

  ```
  public class AppStart
      : MvxNavigatingObject
      , IMvxAppStart      
  {
      public void Start(object hint = null)
      {
          var authService = Mvx.Resolve<IMySerice>();
          if (authService.IsLoggedIn)
          {
              ShowViewModel<HomeViewModel>();
          }
          else
          {
              ShowViewModel<LoginViewModel>();
          }
      }
  }
  ```

  (you can see another example in https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/v3/Sample%20-%20CirriousConference/Cirrious.Conference.Core/ApplicationObjects/AppStart.cs)

  This can be registered in App.cs startup using:

  ```
  RegisterAppStart(new AppStart());
  ```