# View is not locating the Viewmodel with default VML in MVVMCross

Tags: c#, android, mvvmcross

I'm trying to create a Portable Class such that I can use that across the platforms. It is working fine in Windows Phone 8.1 App. But when it comes to Android, then it is showing the Viewmodel as null and DataContext as Null in debugger which breaks the application debugger. When I create another viewmodel and view to test the app, its working fine on android too. What can be the possible reasons.

**EDIT** : It is crashing due to the constructor , in which I am passing the business Logic instance. So , Constructor is necessary i think but in that case it is crashing.I am not trying to resolve the ViewModel , i am trying to resolve the Service instance in ViewModel and for the purpose of MVVM, I am keeping the Service out from Droid Project so base.OnCreate(bundle) does not come into scene anyways.

public BookViewModel(ILogic _logic)
       {

```
       logic = _logic;
       //var ss= Mvx.Resolve<ILogic>();
      //var  x = Mvx.CanResolve<ILogic>();
       _details = logic.Read();

   }
```

Below is the Logic Code :

```
 public class Logic : ILogic
{

    #region Attributes

    List<Detail.Detail> _details = new List<Detail.Detail>();
    DataLayer.DataLayer dl = new DataLayer.DataLayer();

    #endregion

    #region .ctor

    public Logic()
    {
        populateList();
    }

    #endregion

    #region Methods


   private void populateList()
    {
        _details = dl.Access();
    }
```

Below is the App.cs in ViewModel in which CanResolve is giving **False**

public class App : Cirrious.MvvmCross.ViewModels.MvxApplication
    {

```
    #region Methods
    public override void Initialize()
    {
        Mvx.RegisterType<ILogic, Logic>();
        var ss = Mvx.CanResolve<ILogic>();

        RegisterAppStart<ViewModels.BookViewModel>();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few questions and answers around similar to this - e.g. similar to [MVVMCross ViewModel construction failure notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24086927/mvvmcross-viewmodel-construction-failure-notifications/24089761#24089761)

The basic answer is that MvvmCross cannot resolve the ViewModel during the constructor - you have to wait until after the `base.OnCreate(bundle)` call - at this point the ViewModel will be resolved.

There's also a bit more about when ViewModel's are located in [Who should create view model instances in MvvmCross](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19953747/who-should-create-view-model-instances-in-mvvmcross/19957464#19957464) and [CoreDispatcher.HasThreadAccess "breaking change"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16100110/coredispatcher-hasthreadaccess-breaking-change/16109220#16109220) (and probably a few other places too)

Comment: Actually , I am not resolving the viewmodel. I am resolving the Service which I am using in ViewModel.And i am waiting until until the base.OnCreate(bundle) but it breaks there at that point. And in the LOCALE , it shows me DataContext and ViewModel as null .I tried to workout this by resolving the service instance inside the OnStart() but breaks again.

Comment: Please edit the question to provide code and a clear question about what is failing. Your question curly says the view cannot locate the view model and that "it is crashing due to the constructor" - if that is ambiguous then you can use edit the question to improve it.

Comment: I got the error now . I was trying to resolve the Service in two ViewModels but then in that case i am wondering for the solution of using the instance of same service in two VMs .